# Python config parser to get all the values from a section?

Tags: python, parsing, configparser

I want to get all the values from a section using config parser

I used this but it gives only the first value

```
def ConfigSectionMap(section):
  dict1 = {}
  options = Config.options(section)
  for option in options:
    try:
      dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option)
      if dict1[option] == -1:
        DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
    except:
      print("exception on %s!" % option)
      dict1[option] = None
    return dict1


  Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
  Config.read("/etc/harvest.conf")
  print ConfigSectionMap("files").values()
```

Comment: Your `return` is not properly indented and your function returns in the first iteration of the for loop. Remove two spaces.

Comment: Get all the keys from the section without the keys from the DEFAULT section 
>>> cfg['geometry'].keys() - cfg['DEFAULT'].keys()

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Make it a dict:

```
dict(Config.items('Section'))
```

Answer (score 15):

You can make it a list if ordering is important

```
list(Config.items('Section'))
```

Comment: Does not work for me (the version with dict does). I get this:  *** Error in argument: "(Config.items('Section'))".